# Cannot use constructor variable after calling it with this()

Tags: java, constructor

I made a program for the sole purpose of testing out constructors.

In the constructor Car(), I declare int hello = 5. But when I call that constructor with this(), I still cannot use hello (it cannot be resolved to a variable, AND eclipse complains that hello is never used). I thought that calling this() would run the code in Car(), therefore extending the scope of hello. What is wrong?

```
class Car {
    public Car(){
        int hello = 5;
    }
    public Car(int howmany){
        this();
        howmany+=hello;
    }
}
```

I thought that calling this() would run the code in Car(), thus extending the scope of hello to within the Car(int howmany) constructor?

I am new to Java so there may be something elementary I don't know.

Comment: What are you even trying to do..

Comment: Do you know what variable scope is? What is the scope of `hello`?

Comment: This isn't for any purpose, just to test out constructors. @SotiriosDelimanolis I thought that calling this() would run the code in Car(), thus extending the scope of hello to within the Car(int howmany) constructor. Seems like this isn't the case..

Comment: Also... I feel like any questions viewed as elementary are just downvoted. I am new to Java so it's not unusual to have elementary questions. Unless I did something against stackoverflow policies?

Comment: If you hover over the downvote button, you'll be able to read reasons for downvoting. _shows lack of research effort_ and _not useful_ apply here. That last comment of yours (about you thinking that extending scope is possible) would have been useful here.

Comment: Variable `hello` is localy created and dies in first constructor.

Comment: Start viewing constructors as methods. In this case, one method invoking another method. There's no _extension of code_ going on. That is not something that exists in Java.

Comment: That's the answer I needed, thanks! I would choose it if it were a real answer. I misunderstood what this() does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hello is declared inside the constructor, so it has a scope only inside the constructor. I dont know what are you trying to do but maybe you need to declare hello as an attribute of Car.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
class Car {

  int hello;
  int howMany;

  public Car(){
    hello = 5;
  }

  public Car(int howmany){
    this();
    this.howMany = howmany + hello;
  }
}
```

This declares `hello` and `howMany` variables as instance variables and now they will be available to all class methods and constructors.

Answer (score -1):

Currently, the variable 'hello' can only be called from inside the constructor. A variable can only be called from the same part of the code it was declared within; if it is within a method it will only be accessible through that method.

If you would like to make this variable accessible from all methods within that class, declare 'hello' before the constructor methods and add the word 'private' in front of it. If you want all classes to be able to access it, add 'public' in front of it. Here is an example of both:

```
class Car {
private int hello; //Accessible from within only the class
public int hello; //Accessible from other classes
    public Car(){
        int hello = 5;
    }
    public Car(int howmany){
        this();
        howmany+=hello;
    }
}
```

I hope this helped. Just remember that **where** you declare a variable matters, as do the tags in front of it. And keep in mind not to declare two version of the hello variable like I did up there, that was just an example.